# How to build Visual Studio Code with a custom Electron binary?

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

I have been working on some changes to the Chromium codebase that I would like to test in VSCode. To perform this, I have to basically follow the build chain of: Chromium -> Electron -> VSCode. My main goal is to build this custom VSCode binary to perform some testing.

For the Chromium -> Electron part, I managed to perform it by adding a `.patch` file to the `patches/chromium` directory and add the filename of that `.patch` file to the `.patches` file in the same directory.

However, for the Electron -> VSCode part, I am currently stuck. I did take a look at the [issues page of VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) and I see some people mentioning a "swap" of the Electron binary to perform some testing, but the exact methods on how to do it were never mentioned anywhere either in the [Wiki pages](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki) or in the various issues.

After executing `yarn`, I did find an `electron` binary in `node_modules/electron/dist/`, but replacing that file with my custom Electron binary does not work as it seems that the generated `code-oss` file is still using the older, original Electron binary.

Similarly, after executing `yarn watch`, there is a `code-oss` file in `.build/electron/`, but replacing it before executing `scripts/code.sh` also does not work (it resulted in an error message regarding a version mismatch between V8 binary and snapshot).

I also tried tracing the execution of the [`scripts/code.sh` file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/scripts/code.sh) and I ended up at the `getElectron` function in the [`build/lib/electron.ts` file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/build/lib/electron.ts). It seems that it sets some configuration values and downloads an Electron build by using the [`@vscode/gulp-electron` package](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-gulp-electron). Perhaps there is a way to override this download process in some way?

I am performing this on Ubuntu 20.04, AMD64. I would appreciate any help regarding this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I was already in the right direction, but I was misdirected by the "V8 version mismatch" error message.

First, follow the [official Electron build instructions](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/development/build-instructions-gn) to build Electron.

```bash
$ mkdir electron && cd electron
$ gclient config --name "src/electron" --unmanaged https://github.com/electron/electron
$ gclient sync --with_branch_heads --with_tags
$ cd src
$ export CHROMIUM_BUILDTOOLS_PATH=`pwd`/buildtools
$ gn gen out/Release --args="import(\"//electron/build/args/release.gn\")"
$ ninja -C out/Release electron
```

The commands that I didn't run were under the "Packaging" header on the official instructions page. I ended up executing these 2 commands as well since they would create a handy ZIP file for us to use:

```bash
$ electron/script/strip-binaries.py -d out/Release
$ ninja -C out/Release electron:electron_dist_zip
```

A `dist.zip` file will be created in the `out/Release` directory. Replace the contents of the `.build/electron/` directory at wherever you have put your VSCode project files with the contents of this ZIP file. Also, remember to rename the main Electron binary from `electron` to `code-oss`.

This approach of replacing the contents of the `.build/electron/` directory did the trick. The thing that I was missing was that I had to replace the whole directory, instead of just the `code-oss` file (which is just the main Electron binary but renamed). In retrospect, it made sense why the "V8 version mismatch" error was printed, but it didn't click for me until I spent some more time on it.

I also did the following modification (basically commenting out the calls to `getElectron`) to ensure that the build scripts did not accidentally replace my custom Electron files:

```
diff --git a/build/lib/preLaunch.js b/build/lib/preLaunch.js
index 846e649a7c2..61d6510bd74 100644
--- a/build/lib/preLaunch.js
+++ b/build/lib/preLaunch.js
@@ -41,7 +41,7 @@ async function ensureCompiled() {
 }
 async function main() {
     await ensureNodeModules();
-    await getElectron();
+    // await getElectron();
     await ensureCompiled();
     // Can't require this until after dependencies are installed
     const { getBuiltInExtensions } = require('./builtInExtensions');
diff --git a/build/lib/preLaunch.ts b/build/lib/preLaunch.ts
index 3d3f513b591..3f1021d8ed0 100644
--- a/build/lib/preLaunch.ts
+++ b/build/lib/preLaunch.ts
@@ -47,7 +47,7 @@ async function ensureCompiled() {
 
 async function main() {
        await ensureNodeModules();
-       await getElectron();
+       // await getElectron();
        await ensureCompiled();
 
        // Can't require this until after dependencies are installed
```